# How to change starting point of a C# program to another method?

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, main-method

I know that we can have many overload of Main method and have different methods.
But to run the C# class, class should have main() method with signature as public static void main(String[] args){} If you do any modification to this signature, the compilation will be successful. But, You will get a runtime error as main method not found. 
I have two questions.

1. How to change the starting point of an C# program to another
   method(including any overload of Main method)?
2. What is the default
   class is chosen for run? Can we change it ??

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   }

Comment: Take a look at the "Application Startup"  section the language specification (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts - C# 6 draft spec.)

Comment: Are you referring to a dll?  The main function in a dll is optional and only is used when the dll is started from cmd.exe.  Any public method can be called in a dll when called from another complied application.